# glGenBuffers function usage

Tags: opengl

For each buffer type, there a special function to generate names for it like `glGenFramebuffers` for framebuffers, `glGenRenderbuffers` for render buffers, and `glGenTextures` for textures.

But there is a function called `glGenBuffers`. What types of buffers does this function generate? & how these buffers can be used in my program?

Comment: Did you try reading [this](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glGenBuffers.xml) and manybe [this](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glBindBuffer.xml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glGenBuffers` allocates a name for a "Buffer Object". An OpenGL Buffer Object represents a block of memory which can be accessed by both the application and the GPU (though typically not by both at the same time). OpenGL can use the contents of a buffer object for a variety of purposes, and a single buffer object may be used for more than one purpose over its lifetime, though in practice buffer objects are often created exclusively for one type of data.

You can get an idea for the uses that a buffer object has by looking at the list of binding points to which you can attach a buffer object (using the `glBindBuffer` function). For example:

- `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER​` - OpenGL will read vertex data from the buffer object.
- `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER​` - OpenGL will read vertex indices (e.g., for `glDrawElements`) from the buffer object.
- `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER​` - Functions that read pixel data (e.g., `glTexImage2D`) will read that data from the buffer object.

And many more.

For more information, see the OpenGL wiki page for [Buffer Object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object).

Comment: So the main difference between render buffers and these buffers are the binding points. These buffers can be considered as a more generic buffers that can be bound to many binding points, unlike the render buffer for example that should only be bound to `GL_RENDERBUFFER`. Is that right?

Comment: They're different object types. Like different classes in an object oriented programming language. OpenGL has several such object types, which include renderbuffers, framebuffers, textures, and buffer objects. A "buffer object" is no more closely related to a "renderbuffer object" or "framebuffer object" than to a "texture object". For example, you can't use `glBindBuffer` to bind a renderbuffer object -- `glBindBuffer` works only on buffer objects.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My misunderstanding was because I thought they are related

Comment: I think it's a fairly common mistake: the names can be a little confusing.

Comment: Indeed, had they taken a page from Microsoft and called them something less confusing like perhaps RenderTarget Objects or DrawSurface Objects instead of RBO/FBO this confusion would come up a lot less. I am just glad that nobody confuses ATI's very old extension: [`GL_ATI_vertex_array_object`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ATI/vertex_array_object.txt) (which is the basis for VBOs) with the concept by the same name in GL 3.0; that one would be a nightmare to explain.